# how to create Grid view with customized column from different table with asp.net and c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

now i am very confused with how to create gridview with the following structure and criteria:

note: the gridview will take data from different tables

columns:
1. IDcol the unique value and it will be from tableA(as text)
2. Date it will from also tableA(as text)
3. link1 it will be hyperlink to another page and the parameter for the url will be 'IDcol' column value but the text displayed will changed if this record is exists in tableB with the same 'IDcol' the dispalyed will be "view/edit" if not exists it will be "Add New"

database structure:

### tableA:

```
IDcol as (primary key),
Date
```

### tableB:

```
ID,
IDcol as (foreign key from tableA).
other fields
```

---

so i need populate the gridview using loop because i have to check for each row and use some conditions

sorry if my way of description is not clear but i am really confused

---

My code for deleting part:

```
        <asp:LinkButton ID="DeleteLink" runat="server" Text="Delete"     CommandName="Delete"></asp:LinkButton>
        </ItemTemplate>
        <ItemStyle Width="100px" />
        </asp:TemplateField>


 DeleteCommand="DELETE VisitsInfo WHERE ID=@VID">


 <DeleteParameters>
                <asp:Parameter Name="VID" Type="Int64" />
            </DeleteParameters>
```

in code behind :

```
 protected void GridView1_RowDeleting(object sender, GridViewDeleteEventArgs e)
    {

            int VID = int.Parse(GridView1.DataKeys[0].Value.ToString());
            SqlDataSourceVisits.DeleteParameters[0].DefaultValue = VID.ToString();

    }
```

when i click on delete link to delete row it works but when refresh the page its delete another row without click the delete link so why that happened??

Comment: Just a suggestion, why not get all the columns into one table while you need to loop through and check for *some conditions*

Comment: because i need only specific columns to display for user and it will depends on the data in database from many tabled not only one and this the problem

Comment: What i meant was while you loop based on your conditions add the required values to one main table (you can look up in as many tables as you may have) and then push the data into the required cells (hope you have the columns to be displayed fixed)

Comment: mmm i think i will try your suggestion and tell :) thanks

Comment: @speciallife - have you tried something uptill

Comment: now i am trying to use datatable way to see if its work well with my case or not :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No matter how many tables you are using to display data in a Gridview, the best and more flexible approach is to use OnRowDataBound.

```
//do some database queries to return the appropriate value
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
private void Bind()
{
    //set up the dt with all the required data from single or multiple tables
}

//Then in the page Load method, call the above Bind method
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     if (!IsPostBack)
     {
          Bind();
     }
}

//then do something like the following 
int idx = 0;    
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    //do some database queries to return the appropriate value, then do something like the following
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        e.Row.Cells[0].Text = dt.Rows[idx][0];
        e.Row.Cells[1].Text = dt.Rows[idx][1];
        //or maybe
        ((TextBox)e.Row.Cells[0].FindControl("textBox1")).Text = dt.Rows[idx][0];
        ((Label)e.Row.Cells[1].FindControl("label2")).Text = dt.Rows[idx][1];
        ((CheckBox)e.Row.Cells[1].FindControl("chkbx1")).Selected = (bool)dt.Rows[idx][2]; 

        idx++;
    }
}
```

And as Pranay said, you may wish to use Linq and join to get the required data from all tables, though, you can still get them in any other way you feel comfortable with

Comment: thanks a lot of your response and answer i did it with sqldatasource then make edit for the content in OnRowDataBound and your suggestion is nice too thanks :) but i have now another problem with delete command when i refresh the page the event OnRowDeleting fired again and delete another row without click delete link myself can you help me with that please??

Comment: ok i will show you my code  for this page maybe i am making big mistake :D

Comment: now check my question again please i added the part for deleting :) thanks in advance

Comment: I wonder how and where you bind the data?! How do you perform delete? I noticed you said you are using SqlDataSource, if so, delete should be really easy, just add DeleteCommand to SqlDataSource & no need for OnDeleting nor OnDeleted.

    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ApplicationServices %>"
        SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM UserDetails" DeleteCommand="Delete From UserDetails Where UserName=@UserName">    </asp:SqlDataSource>

Let me know the results.

If this solves your issue please don't forget to tag question as answered.

Comment: There is no need for GridView1_RowDeleting at all, you may keep it empty of code if you wish. Just add CommandDelete and CommandField as shown in my previous comment or your LinkButton, replace UserName=@Username with ID=@ID

Comment: really Thank you very much you got it and helped me to find my mistake i did as you say and its working now :)

Answer (score 0):

Create a dataview from the two tables and bind the grid to it. While rendering the GridView, in row events ie. rowbound, you can put your conditions.

Answer (score 0):

If I am getting it right, you want to select some column (like A, B, C) from multiple tables and then show them in gridview. If it is, it can be done in various ways.
1. Create a custom `DataSet` with your required datacolumns in it and fill it using the select query. Then bind the dataset into gridview.
2. Create a `DataTable` with your required datacolumns in it and fill it using the select query. Then bind the table into gridview.
3. Add your required columns directly into gridview then add data items in it using loop.
**Note:** In any cases, **UNCHECK** the "**AutoGenerateColumn**" option of the gridview for smooth operation.

Comment: yeah you are right i want to try with your third suggestion because it will satisfy my needs to check for some conditions